# Treetools package - computational linguistics

Tags: python, nlp, package, linguistics

How can I obtain the LCFRS grammar using treetools? I used the following terminal command

```
treetools grammar wsj_0001.prd output leftright --dest-format rcg --markov v:1 h:2
```

where `wsj_0001.prd` is a tree and the output file I get is empty.

`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treetools/0.1.0` - I used the last command form the ones listed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a sentence from the Clark paper